# My ImagePickerView automatically stacks two times?

Tags: swiftui, uiimagepickercontroller

**I don't know the problem. Here...**
Everything works. All the images are stored and when I navigate back all the images are displayed as I want. Only problem I could.t understand is why the pickerView is stacking up when it gets saved in firestore for two times and I have to navigate back same view 2 times to get to  where I was.

**This is my model:**

```
struct Images: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    @ServerTimestamp var addedTime: Timestamp?
    var imageUrl: String?
}
```

**This is my ViewModel:**

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class ImageListViewModel: ObservableObject {
   
    @Published var imageList = [Images]()
    
    @Published var imageRepository = ImageRepository()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        imageRepository.$imageListInFirestore
            .assign(to: \.imageList, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
    }
    func getImages(){
        imageRepository.getImageListFromFirestore()
    }
    
    func uploadImage(image: UIImage?) {
        
        guard let image = image else {
            return
        }
        imageRepository.uploadImage(image: image)
    }
    
    func downloadImage(){
        
    }
}
```

**This my repository:**

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import Combine

class ImageRepository: ObservableObject {
    @Published var imageListInFirestore = [Images]()
    
    
   
    
    
    let dbCollectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("images")
    
    let firestoreStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images")
    
        
    init() {

        getImageListFromFirestore()
    }
    
    func getImageListFromFirestore() {
        dbCollectionRef
            .order(by: "addedTime")
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                self.imageListInFirestore = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap({ document in
                    do {
                        let result = try document.data(as: Images.self)
                        return result
                    }
                    catch{
                        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        
                    }
                    return nil
                })
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    
    
    /*
    func getImageList(){
        
        Storage.storage().reference().child("images").listAll { resultList, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            
            for item in resultList.items {
                let imageName = item.name
                
                Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(imageName)").downloadURL { url, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }

                    guard let url = url else {
                        print("No url found")
                        return
                    }

                    self.images.append(ImageUrlList(imageURL: url))
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
 */
    
    func downloadImage(_ path: String) {
       
        var imageKoUrl: String = ""
        
        
        Storage.storage().reference().child(path).downloadURL { url, err in

            if let err = err {
                print("Error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                
            }
            guard let url = url else {
                 return
            }
            imageKoUrl =  url.absoluteString
            //print(imageKoUrl)
            
            var image = Images()
            image.imageUrl = imageKoUrl
            do {
                let _ = try self.dbCollectionRef.addDocument(from: image)
            }catch{
                fatalError("Writing to firestore error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            

        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    func uploadImageInFirestore() {
        
    }
    
    func uploadImage(image: UIImage?) {
        guard let image = image else {
            return
        }
        
        if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1){
            print(imageData)
            let storage = Storage.storage()
            let metaData = StorageMetadata()
            metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
            //let storage = Storage.storage() //firebase storage
            storage.reference().child("images/\(UUID()).jpg").putData(imageData, metadata: metaData) { data, err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                }else{
                    print("Image uploaded succesfully in storage")
                    //print(data?.path)
                    guard let data = data else {
                        return
                    }
                    self.downloadImage(data.path!)
                    
                    
                }
       
            }
        }else {
            print("Could't compress image as image data")
        }
    }
    
}
```

**These are my views:**

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseStorage
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct ImageListView: View {
    
    //@State private var imageUrlList = [URL]()
    
   // @State private var imageURLList = [ImageUrlList]()
    @ObservedObject var imageListVM =  ImageListViewModel()
    
 
    
    
    
    
    
    private let threeColumnGrid = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40)),
    ]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("List of images")
                    
                    if imageListVM.imageList.isEmpty {
                        Text("No images")
                            .padding()
                    }else{
                        LazyVGrid(columns: threeColumnGrid, content: {
                            ForEach(imageListVM.imageList){ image in
                                
                                
                                
                                GeometryReader { gr in
                                    
                                    ImageFromFirebase(imageUrl: URL(string: image.imageUrl!))
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            .clipped()
                            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                        })
                    }
                    
                }
                .padding()
                
                .navigationTitle("Photos")
                .toolbar {
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ImagePickerView(),
                        label: {
                            Text("Add image")

                        })
                        
                        
                    
                }
            }
            //.onAppear(perform: imageListVM.getImages)
            
        }
        
    }
}
struct ImageFromFirebase: View {
    
    @State var imageUrl: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        if let imageUrl = imageUrl {
            AnimatedImage(url: imageUrl)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
        }
        
    }
}
```

**and pickerview**

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ImagePickerView: View {
    
    @State private var buttonPressed = false
    @State private var isShowPhotoLibrary = false
    @State private var showCamera = false
    
    @State private var image: UIImage?
    
    @State private var imageURl = URL(string: "")
    
    @ObservedObject var imageListVM = ImageListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if image != nil {
                Image(uiImage: image!)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }else {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
          
            VStack(spacing: 10){
                
                Group{
                    
                    HStack{
                        Button(action: {
                            self.isShowPhotoLibrary.toggle()
                            
                        }, label: {
                            HStack{
                                Image(systemName: "photo")
                                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                                Text("Photo Library")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    
                                
                            }
                            .padding()
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 50)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .cornerRadius(20)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        })
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            //imageListVM.downloadImage()
                        
                            
                        }, label: {
                            HStack{
                                Image(systemName: "camera")
                                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                                Text("Take picture")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    
                                
                            }
                            .padding()
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 50)
                            .background(Color.red)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .cornerRadius(20)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        })
     
                    }
                }
                
                //upload image to firebase
                Button(action: {
                    guard let image = image else {
                        
                        print("No image.Choose image first")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    
                    //uploadImage(image)
                    
                    imageListVM.uploadImage(image: image)
                    
                    
                }, label: {
                    HStack{
                        Image(systemName: "photo")
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                        Text("Upload to firebase")
                            .font(.headline)
                        
                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 50)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                })
                
            }
            
            Text("URL of image: \(imageURl?.absoluteString ?? "no url")")
            
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowPhotoLibrary , content: {
            
            ImagePicker(selectedImage: self.$image, sourceType: .photoLibrary)
            
        })
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Change ObservedObject to StateObject in ImageListView

Comment: It fixed the view stacking problem but now I can't get the list of images in imageList view.